# Add elements to vector if condition satisfied

Tags: matlab, vector, conditional-statements, updating

I have the following problem: I want to create an empty vector that gets updated (increases in value +1) when the following condition is met:

```
case 'RightArrow'
if strcmp(Correct_Response, 'FALSE');
Accuracy = 1;

else
Accuracy = 0;
Snd('Play',sin(0:500),2000)
```

When Accuracy = 0 the vector should increase by +1 every time this occurs. When this occurred more than 4 times (so the empty vector reaches a value >4) the program should notify me... I struggle with creating this continuously updated vector!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with _increases in value +1_? Do mean the size increasing (i.e., first, empty vector, then one element, two elements ... what values do the elements have in this case?) or simply a counter (i.e., starting with 0 and then the value is increase to 1, 2, ...)?

Comment: a counter would also do! I just want to count the instances when Accuracy = 0 !

Comment: Then simply create your counter with `counter = 0;` at the beginning and add `counter = counter+1` to the `else` block.

Comment: How can an empty vector have a value??

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I can see no vectors in the example. I guess that you want to count errors. Then use a counter instead. `counter = 0; if (correct), %do something; else, counter = counter+1; % do something else; end `. Then you can check the counter value in a while loop. `while (~quit && counter<4) %do a lot of stuff; end` (or alternatively only use `quit` and set `quit` to true if the error is frequent enough).